# Using SDL with the g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++, sdl-2

I'm trying to run this test code from the SDL website but I dont understand where to put the downloaded files and how to reference them using the `g++` compiler. I've been trying to using the `-I` command but I dont quite understand that either. I keep getting the `"fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory #include<SDL.h> "`
Using windows and sublime text editor and `g++` compiler

Comment: Hello AsianRice, I think you forget to share the code.

Comment: Is there something in particular that you don't understand about the `-I` option?

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the g++ manual:

"-I dir

Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files. Directories named by -I are searched before the standard system include directories. If the directory dir is a standard system include directory, the option is ignored to ensure that the default search order for system directories and the special treatment of system headers are not defeated . If dir begins with "=", then the "=" will be replaced by the sysroot prefix; see --sysroot and -isysroot."

As for your error, I would try `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`. This could vary based on the version you are using. If that doesn't work I would just make sure you have the correct path when including in the compiler as a flag.